# How to cache a table in spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have to join 2 sources with my spark streaming data. These 2 sources will be refreshed once in a month, which means that the data for these sources will change only once in a month.

So, I thought of creating a table from dataframe for these sources and then caching it. And uncache the table before refreshing it next month.

```
spark.catalog.cacheTable
spark.catalog.uncacheTable
```

Could you please let me know if this is the correct approach. My spark version is 2.4

Below is the pseudo code

```
private void loadData() {
    //Read Customer data. This should be refreshed once is a month.
     DataSet<Row> cutomerData = SparkOperationUtils.loadDataSouce(spark, <path of the data>, <table name that has to be created after reading>);
     spark.catalog().cacheTable(cutomerData)
}

public void initJob() {

     ....
     loadDaata();
     nextRefershedDate = getNextRefreshedDate(); // this will be in milliseconds

}


private void enhanceStay(string folderName) throws Exception {
     String staySourcePath = folderName + prefix;
     String outputPath = outputHdfsPrefix + separator + folderName;

     DataSet<Row> realtimeDataSource = 
     SparkOperationUtils.loadDataSouce(spark, staySourcePath, sourceDataTable);  // loadDataSouce method accepts spark, path of the data that it has to read, and the table it has to create from the data

      if (nexRefreshedDate < currentDate) {
        spark.catalog().uncacheTable(cutomerData)
        loadDaata();
        nextRefershedDate = getNextRefreshedDate(); // this will be in milliseconds
     }


     DataSet<Row> realtimeDataSourceDF = .. //join the 2 tables from sourceDataTable and cutomerData

.....

 }
```

---

EDIT

I'm trying to cache the file in spark-shell. My input file size is 2.9GB and the driver memory for spark-shell is 10GB. I tried to cache the file. Though 10G is mentioned when launching the spark-shell, only 5.5GB is allocated for the driver(Attached the spark UI).

[image]

What I dont understand is that all the storage memory (5.3GB) and additional disk of 2.8GB is used for caching 2.9GB of file.

Could you please let me know what exactly happens when we do the cache. Why almost 3 times RAM is used. Is this because my file format is parquet and the file is exploded when reading into memory? I tried to create a text file from this just to know the file size. Text file size was around 21GB.

Thanks

Comment: can you post complete code snippet and explan?

Comment: Hi @RamGhadiyaram, thanks for the reply. I still didnt work on the coding. So edited my post with psuedo code. Can you please take a look and correct me if the approach is wrong.

Comment: Hi @RamGhadiyaram, I tried to cache the DF and use this. But its taking around 7-8mins to cache which is a serious isse...any idea how to do this

Comment: 7-8 mins for what volume of data?

Comment: Hi @RamGhadiyaram, I have edited my question. Its just 2.9 GB of data. But I'm running the program in cluster mode. I only have 1 server of 36GB RAM and running in spark standalone. Thanks